# Part of html with thymeleaf not displayed

Tags: html, thymeleaf, display

I'm trying to create a registration form. But when I try to run my code, part of it doesn't appear on the screen. I use thymeleaf for work with Spring MVC controllers. I looked Thymeleaf tutorials, stackoverflow, etc... but have not seen any solution.
Please tell me what I do wrong or where I can read about solution of this problem.
Below I put the snippet of my html code.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

```
<div class="container" id="container-middle">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="register-form" method="post" th:action="@{/post-user-info}" th:object="${user}">
        <h2 id="form-header">Sign up for BlaBla</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="login" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Login:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" id="login" placeholder="Login" class="form-control" th:field="*{login}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first-name" class="col-sm-5 control-label">First name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="First name" class="form-control" th:field="*{firstName}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last-name" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Last name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" id="last-name" placeholder="Last name" class="form-control" th:field="*{lastName}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="birthDate" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Date of birth:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="date" id="birthDate" class="form-control" th:field="*{birthDate}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-5">Gender:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{sex}" th:value="${female}">Female
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{sex}" th:value="${male}">Male
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I understand what's wrong. A don't pass any model from my controller to template for the binding result. i'm stupid XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't pass any model from controller to template, so it couldn't put there any result.

Answer (score 0):

That's it! something like ...

```
public String goAdd(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute(new DtoCustomer());
    return "customer/edit";
}
```